# I am not sure how to fix the "TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, int found" in my code?

Tags: python-3.x

I am having trouble with the second function in converting it back to the original string. I see what the issue is as when I call previous function, the tuple has a string and an int. So I assume I must convert that int to a string. But based on the code I wrote, I am not sure where to convert it. Hopefully, I am on the right track with this. My professor is very strict when it comes to certain things I cannot use any built-ins. Thank you. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**
Will put code back soon

Comment: What is `rle` in `rle("Hello!")`?

Comment: Oh I apologize I was testing and forgot to put the correct name. That is supposed to call the previous function

Comment: Well j and i are iterators. But i think the issue is that when it gets the result from the first function. It gets it as a list of tuples. And then from there I would turn it back to a string. As you can see above, ("a", 2) for example, it is probably giving me that error because it is "a" 1 when i do print those variables to see what it is. The problem is I am not sure how to fix the int, without going beyond what he has taught us. I was going to use "for character, count ...." and that would solve all my problems. But I am not sure if he will be okay with that. Is there another way?

Comment: Hi Angel Baby.. I'm not sure why you removed your code. It was fine as it is there. If you modify to solve another issue then it should be asked as a different question. you may refer to this question, no problem. I will elaborate on your comment in the comments with my answer.

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense. I did not want anyone to downvote it for any silk mistakes. I am hew here so I am still getting used to everything.

Comment: Question should be rolled back to revision 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is in this case to use print statements for debugging.

```
def rldecode(rlencode):
    decodedString = ""
    L = []
    for i in rlencode:
        counter =  0
        occurrence = i[1]             # tuple (item, occurrence) == positions (0, 1)
        for j in range(occurrence):
            L.append(i[0])
    return ''.join(L)
```

Comment: I just realized what does the “decodedString” variable do. I know I had that in my code and I was going to use it as the counter variable after I fixed the other issue and increment it. I’m wondering if that should just be in a comment as based on the code, that variable is not used

Comment: As mentioned earlier I would elaborate a bit on what went wrong. The inpunt in rldeocde is `[('H', 1), ('e', 1), ('l', 2), ('o', 1), ('!', 1)]`. As your for-loop was written pythons cde interpreter itters through that list of tuples. The second item is a integer (1 from ('H', 1). That initiated the reported traceback error  **str expected, int given**.

Comment: It suffices here with the mentioning of: `decodedString= "".join(L) return (decodedString)` as I just did ;-)

Comment: Thank you for all your help!! :)